# Using Query, Index and Split within an arrayformula not working

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet that has a column (D) with values separated by a "-", I'm trying to split the value and get the second half and use that in a query to look up and fetch another value.

For example Sheet 1

```
Col D         |
--------------|
67009-XYZ0001 |
```

Sheet 2

```
Col C       | Col D | Col E    |
------------|-------|----------|
XYZ0001.jpg |       | test.com |
```

The formula should result in "**test.com**"

It works when used by it's self in a cell.

```
=query(Info!A:F,"Select E where C contains '"& index(SPLIT(D2,"-"),0,2) &"'")
```

Using it in an array formula without query the split and index works fine.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"GET URL,index(SPLIT(D:D,"-"),0,2)))
```

But when I try using it in an array formula along with query it doesn't work.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"GET URL",query(Info!A:F,"Select E where C contains '"& index(SPLIT(D:D,"-"),0,2) &"'")))
```

Is there any other way of achieving this.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

I have shared the [link to the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wk0CKqcuwAhxtZhNd4eokwNXGdJhSWzeKGsHQcKJKVQ/edit?usp=sharing)

- Sheet 1 shows the wrong result
- Sheet 3 shows the desired result,    but    only works in cell.

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet?

Comment: For future reference: Array Formula doesn't work with Query (and couple of different array based formulas)

Comment: Have shared a copy of the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

`=FILTER(VLOOKUP(query(SPLIT(D2:D,"-"),"select Col2"),
{REGEXEXTRACT(Sheet2!C:C,"[^.]*"),Sheet2!E:E},2,),D2:D<>"")`

- `query`: get an index of column 2, function `index` does not work with `arrayformula`
- `vlookup`: get exact match
- `regexExtract`: get the part of text before dot (.).

Note:

- `query` text "contains" does not work with multiple entries, it is not equivalent to [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) statement "in"

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work in the context I want, I have shared the sheet showing the wrong result and the result I want.

Comment: You'll want to use another regex, use `"([^.-]*)\."` instead of `"[^.]*"`

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work, but how do I make the first row the title of the column, right now the first row shows the result.

Comment: Because rows get added through an importrange which is why I was using a arrayformula to add the col title in row 1 and get results regardless of the importrange.

Comment: `={"Custom header" ;  formula}`

Comment: Thank you, is there a way of using this result to vlookup for another result?

=FILTER(VLOOKUP(query(SPLIT(D2:D,"-"),"select Col2"),
{REGEXEXTRACT(Info!C:C,"([^.-]*)\."),Info!E:E},2,),D2:D<>"")